# what exactly is 'flow' in nfdump? can i get tcp sessions with nfdump?

Tags: tcp, statistics, netflow

i need to create some statistics from packets in my network interface, but i'm concerned only for my tcp sessions. i thought i could do that with nfdump and nfsen. because i'm new to this stuff, i dont really get what nfdump defines as 'flow'.

furthermore, can i get statistics with these tools only for the tcp protocol sessions? i mean, for example, that i need to have some average duration of all the connections(srcip-srcport, dstip-dstport pairs) in a server of mine. And for this reason i need the time between the 3WH and the closing of each connection (either with [fin/ack,ack] or with [rst]). Is that possible with nfdump-nfsen?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer here is no: you don't have anything in your list of software that generates netflow information.  It's not going to work.  Netflow collectors do not work as hard as you might like to maintain your idea of a connection - a flow is just a collection of related packets that happen during part of the collection cycle.  For a long-lived session, you can expect to see a few flows.

For your application, you will do better to capture syn-ack and fin packets with tcpdump and analyse the timing of these with your favourite text processing tool.

Also, on the left side of your keyboard, you may find a key with an arrow that allows you to type capital letters.